# FirstOrDefault behavior directly in LINQ statement

Tags: linq

Seems like I may have missed something simple in the syntax, but I'd like to get the results of FirstOrDefault from a linq statement directly without having to store the IEnumerable in a temporary variable first. Something like this:

```
var bestCar = from c in cars
              orderby c.Price
              select first c
```

I know the **first** keyword doesn't actually exist but illustrates what I'd like to do. **I also know I can wrap the from...select statement in parenthesis and call FirstOrDefault** directly but I think the above syntax is cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Enumerable.FirstOrDefault is one of the extension methods in the Enumerable class which does not have a corresponding LINQ syntax element.  The only way to bind to this method is via method call syntax.

You can avoid the temporary by doing the follownig

```
var bestCar = (from c in cars
              orderby c.Price
              select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Although this is meant as an example of `FirstOrDefault()`, it seems best to assume that such an enumerable is already ordered, since ordering is asymptotically inferior to simply `MaxBy(c => c.Price)`.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a way to do that. LINQ is used for defining a query. Doing that doesn't actually cause an evaluation, whereas executing `FirstOrDefault` (or enumerating over it) executes the query.

Answer (score 4):

```
var bestCar = (from c in cars
          orderby c.Price
          select c).FirstOrDefault()
```

OR

```
var bestCar = cars.OrderBy(c => c.Price).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var bestCar = (from c in cars
              orderby c.Price
              select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Sorry I didn't read your question entirely, it seems that this may be exactly what you don't want to do.

Answer (score 2):

In VB you can use 'Aggregate':

```
Dim BestCar = Aggregate c In cars
              Order By c.Price
              Into FirstOrDefault
```