# How to optimize a code using DataTable and Linq?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, datatable, concurrentdictionary

I have 2 **DataTables**. There are about **17000 (table1)** and **100000 (table2)** records.

It's needed to check if the field **"FooName"** contains "ItemName". Also it's needed to take **"FooId"** and then add **"ItemId"** and **"FooId"** to ConcurrentDictionary.

I have this code.

```
DataTable table1;
DataTable table2;           
var table1Select = table1.Select();

ConcurrentDictionary<double, double> compareDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<double, double>();

foreach (var item in table1)
{
         var fooItem = from foo in table2.AsEnumerable()
                  where foo.Field<string>("FooName").Contains(item.Field<string>("ItemName"))
                  select foo.Field<double>("FooId");
         if(fooItem != null && fooItem.FirstOrDefault() != 0)
                {
                    compareDictionary.TryAdd(item.Field<double>("ItemId"), fooItem.FirstOrDefault());
                }
}
```

It works slowly (it takes about 10 minutes to perform the task).

I want to make it faster. How I can optimize it?

Comment: Is `ItemName` one word or a phrase?

Comment: @mtkachenko it's phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three points you can attack:

1. ditch strong typing on field accessors in favour of direct casts: it forces unboxing which you can totally avoid with `doubles` being value types. **upd** as pointed out in comments, you will not avoid unboxing either way, but could potentially save some method call overheads (which is again, arguable). This point can probably be ignored
2. cache reference string so you only access it once per outer loop
3. (i think this is where the biggest gains are) since you seem to always take first result - opt for `FirstOrDefault()` straight in LINQ - don't let it enumerate the whole thing when a match is found

```cs
ConcurrentDictionary<double, double> compareDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<double, double>();

foreach (var item in table1)
    {
        var sample = (string)item["ItemName"]; // cache the value before looping through inner collection
        var fooItem = table2.AsEnumerable()
                            .FirstOrDefault(foo => ((string)foo["FooName"]).Contains(sample)); // you seem to always take First item, so you could instruct LINQ to stop after a match is found
        if (fooItem != null && (double)fooItem["FooId"] != 0)
        {
            compareDictionary.TryAdd((double)item["ItemId"], (double)fooItem["FooId"]);
        }
    }
```

It appears, applying `.FirstOrDefault()` condition to LINQ query syntax will [sort of reduce it to method chain syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534246/firstordefault-behavior-directly-in-linq-statement) anyway, so I'd opt for method chainging all the way and leave it to you to figure out the aesthetics

Comment: I don't believe that is true. `DataRow.Field<T>` for a value type will eventually return `(T)object` which will call IL `unbox.any !T` exactly like `(T)DataRow[fieldname]` does. It does eliminate some method call overhead, however - though of course the JIT might inline them as well.

Comment: @NetMage I am leaning to agree. Initially I had a quick skim through the decompiled code and the first call in line was Unbox<T> which sorta prompted the conclusion. I then had a second look and it seems unboxing is inevitable. Doing cast will still eliminate a few null and DBNull checks it seems. I'll update the answer to not mislead a bit later

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to sacrifice memory for speed, converting from `DataTable` for the fields you need gives about 6x speedup over repeatedly pulling the column data out of `table2`. (This is in addition to the speedup from using `FirstOrDefault`.)

```
var compareDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<double, double>();

var t2e = table2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => (FooName: r.Field<string>("FooName"), FooId: r.Field<double>("FooId"))).ToList();
foreach (var item in table1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => (ItemName: r.Field<string>("ItemName"), ItemId: r.Field<double>("ItemId")))) {
    var firstFooId = t2e.FirstOrDefault(foo => foo.FooName.Contains(item.ItemName)).FooId;

    if (firstFooId != 0.0) {
        compareDictionary.TryAdd(item.ItemId, firstFooId);
    }
}
```

I am using C# `ValueTuple`s to avoid reference object overhead from anonymous classes.